# Getting subcontrol in Repeater

Tags: c#, asp.net, datarepeater, itemdatabound

I am using ASP.NET and C# on .NET 4 to develop a simple app. I have a repeater with an item template containing a few controls; one of them is a label that must be set depending on a complex calculation. I am using the `OnItemDataBound` event to compute the text and set the label's text in the code behind, like this:

```
protected void repRunResults_ItemDataBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
{
    //capture current context.
    Repeater repRunResults = (Repeater)sender;
    Label laMessage = (Label)repRunResults.Controls[0].FindControl("laMessage");
    DSScatterData.RunResultsRow rRunResults = (DSScatterData.RunResultsRow)((DataRowView)(e.Item.DataItem)).Row;

    //show message if needed.
    int iTotal = this.GetTotal(m_eStatus, rRunResults.MaxIterations, rRunResults.TargetLimit);
    if(iTotal == 100)
    {
        laMessage.Text = "The computed total is 100.";
    }
    else
    {
        laMessage.Text = "The computed total is NOT 100.";
    }
}
```

The data source for my repeater contains a few rows, so I would expect that each impression of the repeater would call the event handler and show the message according to the data in the associated row. However, I only get *one* message, which appears on the *first* repeater impression but matches the data for the *last* row in the data source.

It seems like every time the `ItemDataBound` event fires, the controls that my code captures are the same ones, so that I overwrite the message on every impression of the repeater. I have stepped through the code and this is what it is apparently happening.

Any idea why? And how to fix it?

Note. My repeater is nested inside another repeater. I don't think this should be relevant, but it might be.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are grabbing the first one.  You need to use the item that is being passed in like so:

```
protected void repRunResults_ItemDataBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
{
    //capture current context.
    Repeater repRunResults = (Repeater)sender;
    Label laMessage = e.Item.FindControl("laMessage"); //<-- Used e.Item here
    DSScatterData.RunResultsRow rRunResults = (DSScatterData.RunResultsRow)((DataRowView)(e.Item.DataItem)).Row;

    //show message if needed.
    int iTotal = this.GetTotal(m_eStatus, rRunResults.MaxIterations, rRunResults.TargetLimit);
    if(iTotal == 100)
    {
        laMessage.Text = "The computed total is 100.";
    }
    else
    {
        laMessage.Text = "The computed total is NOT 100.";
    }
}
```